# How to prevent Wordnet synonyms from returning duplicate results?

Tags: python, nltk

I have the following function that splits up words and then returns the synonym for it and I am wondering why is it returning so many duplicate values? How can I prevent that from happening so it only displays unique values while maintaining the results in the same format?

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

string = 'Crime Count'

syns = {w : [] for w in string.split(" ")}
for k, v in syns.items():
    for synset in wordnet.synsets(k):
        for lemma in synset.lemmas():
            if lemma.name() not in syns:
                v.append(lemma.name())

syns
```

Results:

```
{'Crime': ['crime',
  'offense',
  'criminal_offense',
  'criminal_offence',
  'offence',
  'law-breaking',
  'crime'],
 'Count': ['count',
  'count',
  'counting',
  'numeration',
  'enumeration',
  'reckoning',
  'tally',
  'count',
  'count',
  'number',
  'enumerate',
  'numerate',
  'count',
  'matter',
  'weigh',
  'consider',
  'count',
  'weigh',
  'count',
  'count',
  'number',
  'count',
  'count',
  'count',
  'bet',
  'depend',
  'look',
  'calculate',
  'reckon',
  'reckon',
  'count']}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you wrote:

```
if lemma.name() not in syns:
```

This checks if the synonym exists in `syn` as a key, not as a value. You could instead do:

```
if lemma.name() not in v:
```

to get your desired result.

Alternatively, you can use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) to prevent adding duplicates.

```
syns = {w : set() for w in string.split(" ")}
for k, v in syns.items():
    for synset in wordnet.synsets(k):
        for lemma in synset.lemmas():
            v.add(lemma.name())
```